# Using IBUS for multiple language input

Tags: language-support, ibus

A month ago or so I migrated from Mint 17.2 to Ubuntu 15.04 and am not regretting it at all, apart from one thing that's pretty annoying and I truly hope It's changeable.

I type in more than 1 language, which requires me to use multiple input methods (right now I'm using English, Russian, Chinese and Korean). I'm using Ibus for this, both when using Mint and on Ubuntu.

Ibus on Mint works slightly different on using Ibus on Ubuntu: On Mint it will remember the last language you have been using, so when you use ctrl+space to go to the next language, it will go to the next language in the list *but, and this is the great part of Ibus in Mint*, if you press ctrl+space again it will go to the language you just used before, instead of going to the next language in the list. This is an extremely handy feature of IBUS in Mint.

In Ubuntu (and Windows for what it matters) You just have to ctrl+space you through the whole list in order, or use shift+ctrl+space to go back through the whole list which can get incredibly annoying and frustrating, especially if you've been working for a while.

I'll show you what I mean by using an example:

Mint: Out of language 1,2,3,4,5 you want to use 1 and 4 for now. Things will go like:

- Using language 1
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- Using language 4
- ctrl+space
- Using language 1
- ctrl+space
- Using language 4
- ctrl+space
- Using language 1
- ctrl+space
- Using language 4

etc,

While IBUS on Ubuntu works like:

- Using language 1
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- Using language 4
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- Using language 1
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- Using language 4
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- Using language 1
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- Using language 4
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- Using language 1
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- ctrl+space
- Using language 4

As you can see, it's really easy to start mixing things up and get kind of really frustrated in the process. Also, on Mint, Ibus will show a huge logo in the middle of the screen with the language are using and/or are changing to, while in Ubuntu the icons are just sitting on the task-bar. Do you know any way to change the way IBUS works on Ubuntu to the way it's working on Mint? Does such a possibility exist?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think you describe the limitations of using IBus on Ubuntu pretty well. However, I'd like to mention that fcitx was integrated in Ubuntu 15.04. fcitx was made the default IM framework for Chinese in 15.04, and in 15.10 fcitx will be the default framework for the other CJKV languages too. Possibly you may want to check it out. Personally I can't really tell if it's more convenient for your situation, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Strangely enough I did not see it; maybe the auto-email function is turned off or so, hence my slow reply. I did try Fcitx, but it was a disaster. I know it's supposed to replace IBUS of some sorts, especially when it comes to Chinese, but it just hardly works when it comes to multiple languages, basically even worse than IBUS.

Comment: I see. Then I suppose that both IBus and fcitx will be easily available in Ubuntu for the forseeable future.

Comment: @Ashwin, Mint 17.2 uses same version 1.5.5 of ibus from trusty U14.04 repository. I doubt some thing change between U14.04 to U15.10.  You can check the configuration using `ibus read-config` of both if you still have Mint 17.2 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is Ubuntu, Mint, or Opensuse ibus is not properly configured to take certain customized Indian language based IM Engines. Ex: Kannada tables. Ibus identifies the tables and their icons, enlist them but not commit to anchor them to system-tray. Unless anchored on the system-tray keying is disaster. but I switched to SCIM and Fcitx. Even SCIM is better than Fcitx for adapting kannada language keying.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail to make it a rock solid answer.